# Combining a parameter host name with literal url in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf, template-engine

I'm trying to get Thymeleaf to build me a URL where the domain part is a parameter, some fragment is a literal string, and the query parameters are also parameterized.

The [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) offers some examples:

```
@{${myDomain}/literalUrl}
@{${myDomain}'/literalUrl'}
@{/literalUrl(query=${queryValue})}
@{'/literalUrl'(query=${queryValue})}
@{${myDomain}(query=${queryValue})}
```

or even

```
<a th:with="baseUrl=${myDomain}" th:href="@{${baseUrl}}(query=${queryValue})}">
```

Separately, all of these work well. But if I try to combine them, the domain part suddenly refuses to resolve:

`@{${myDomain}/literalUrl(query=${queryValue})}` and `@{${myDomain}+'/literalUrl'+(query=${queryValue})}` each resolve to `${myDomain}/literalUrl?query=queryValue`, and

How do I get Thymeleaf to properly generate my url `https://example.com/literalUrl?query=queryValue`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is a legit solution for your problem, but if you concat the literalUrl with the first parameter, it will work. Down side: you need an additional model parameter.

```
<a th:href="@{${linkData+path}(q=${queryParam})}">some link</a>
```

gets

```
<a href="https://example.com/literalUrl?q=queryValue">some link</a>
```

with model params:

```
mv.addObject("linkData", "https://example.com");
mv.addObject("path", "/literalUrl");
mv.addObject("queryParam", "queryValue");
```